# Packet layer field value information

Tags: pyshark

Is there a way to get the packet's layer field value information ?
(i.e. The string info displayed to the right when printing the packet layer)
like the lines below:
**Protocol discriminator: Mobility Management message**
**Skip Indicator: No indication of selected PLMN**

e.g.

```
packets = pyshark.FileCapture(...)
print(packet[0]['IP']):

 .... 0101 = Protocol discriminator: Mobility Management messages (0x5)
 0000 .... = Skip Indicator: No indication of selected PLMN (0)
 ...
 ...
 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply saving it as 
`str(packet[0]['IP'])` 
or 
`packet[0]['IP'].__str__()` 
should do the trick (which is equivalent btw).

For example:

`m_list.append(str(packet[0]['IP']))
with open("out.txt", "w") as f:
f.write(m_list)`

Comment: I dont want all the layer (IP), I want only the description of the value of specific field:
i.e.
for this field:
     
     
"      .... 0101 = Protocol discriminator: Mobility Management messages (0x5)"
I need only the string: "Mobility Management messages"